# Bash evaluation changed in version 4.4?

Tags: bash

I have a bash function which is used to shorten directory names, one way is to shorten "/home/USER" to "~". With bash version 4.2 it produces the expected result, but when version 4.4 the result is expanded to "/home/USER".

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function convertDirRelative()
{
    local retVar="$1" dir
    shift

    dir="$*"
    # [...]
    dir="${dir//${HOME}/~}"

    eval "$retVar=\"\$dir\""
}
output=""
convertDirRelative output $HOME/test
echo "${BASH_VERSION}: Output: $output"
```

When executed with bash 4.2 this is the result, which is expected:

```
4.2.46(2)-release: Output: ~/test
```

When executed with bash 4.4 this is the result:

```
4.4.19(1)-release: Output: /home/USER/test
```

How can I write the function so that it produces the expected result in both bash 4.2 and 4.4?

Comment: Yes, this changed with bash 4.3 ([relevant discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-02/msg00106.html)). But I don't think the current behavior is correct, it doesn't make any sense that `a=ab; echo "${a/b/~}"` prints `a/home/oguz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems to work in both versions:

```
dir=${dir//${HOME}/\~}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the quotationmarks cause an extra expansion?

Comment: I have no idea, I just tried several things and this one worked :-) Double quotes are usually not needed in assignments.